# Who will be the soldiers of Imam Mahdi? (Shia view)

Tags: hadith, shiism, imam-mahdi, soldier

According to the belief of Shiite school of thought, Imam Mahdi (Imam Zaman or factually 12th Imam of Shia)) will reappear as the last Imam of Shiite. They believe that he will come to save the world from oppression. According to the hadiths, many people will join his as his soldiers.

My question is that who will be his soldiers to help him to fight against oppressors?
In fact, will all of his soldiers be Shiite or is it feasible that many other people join him from other sects or even from other religions?

*Note: I'm looking for the answer from Shia's perspective.*

Answer (score 1):

Briefly speaking, it consists of 3 groups (respectively):

- The first group: 313 persons as the main soldiers (perhaps as
  commanders)
- The second group: 10.000 persons
- The third (last group): General Shias and lovers of him who accept
  him after the reappearance... (who seem to be from different
  countries and even various religions (and Allah knows best)

(Of course as my personal perspective: the bad-persons who have hostility with him, won’t have the grace (Tofigh) of …)

And Allah knows best

---

**Reference:**

- [www.mahdaviat.porsemani.ir](https://web.archive.org/web/20190205161729/http://www.mahdaviat.porsemani.ir:80/content/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%B4-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%8A-%D9%BE%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%88-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85)

Answer (score 1):

As he is not only the Imam of the Shia's of Ahlul Baith, but the Imam of the universe, so any person who has some respect and love for the holy household of the Prophet may join his army if Imam wills.
The person maybe off any religion and caste.

Comment: What you replied looks true/informative, but I wish you add ref. or more illustration for that. Anyhow, God bless you for submitting such short helpful answer.